# set value in one entry of an array of objects given value of another key

Tags: javascript

I have the following array of objects in JS:

```
example: [
    { "bucket": "12/01/2019", "isDisabled": true },
    { "bucket": "1/1/2020", "isDisabled": true },
    { "bucket": "2/1/2020", "isDisabled": true }
]
```

I am trying to write a method that sets the `isDisabled` property to false for a given bucket.  This should happen within the `example` array rather than in a copy of the array.  The method takes a bucket parameter, named `selectedBucket`, as input.  For instance, say the object with a bucket of 2/1/2020 is to have its `isDisabled` property set to false.  In this case the value passed to the method as the `selectedBucket` would be 2/1/2020.  Here is what I've tried for the method:

```
edit(selectedBucket) {
    example.forEach(function (element) {
        if (element.bucket === selectedBucket) element.isDisabled = false;
        console.log(element.bucket);
        console.log(element.isDisabled);
    })  
}
```

I would've expected `false` to follow the 2/1/2020 bucket in the console output, but it still says true -

[image]

So how do I go about setting the `isDisabled` property for which ever bucket is passed to the method as the `selectedBucket`?

Comment: Please also show us the code where you are calling `edit()`. Apparently, you didn't pass `"2/1/2020"`, or else it would have worked - the approach with the loop and the conditional statement is fine.

Comment: @Bergi - Yes - that was the problem!  `"02/01/2020"` was being passed in as `selectedBucket`.